# how to parse the letters in vc-date-picker in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to add a title next to the month and date in vc-date-picker using the `:masks` attribute.

Code:

```
<vc-date-picker  
                           class="consultation-calendar"
                            ref="calendar"
                           is-expanded 
:masks="{title:'YYYY MMMM' +  $t(`registration.${selectedOffice.office_key}`)}"
      :first-day-of-week="2"
                            mode="date" 
                            :min-date="new Date(min_consultation_date)"
                            :max-date="new Date(reservation_form.due_date)"
                            v-model="form.consultation_date"
                            @update:from-page="updateCalendarYear"
                            :attributes="calendar_attribute"
                            :disabled-dates="computed_calendar_setup.disabled_dates"
/>
```

As you can see in `:masks` attribute, the title would be . ex: November 2021 and then the name of the office, however on the UI it shows differently because I think `:masks` attribute parsed the equivalent value of the letter into number or month first letter.

Is there any way I can do it the right way? example: November 2021 My Office